# Flutter for web state management

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm toying with Flutter this weekend and I like it so far. I'm going deeper into state management right now. Coming from a React background I tried implementing `redux` with `flutter_redux` but it seems that `flutter_redux` is not working, neither does `BloC` so my question is obious: has anyone managed to have a functional state manager in flutter for web?

Comment: What do you mean by _they don't work_?

Comment: You can't install them as a dependency because they require flutter sdk which is not compatible with flutter web

Answer (score 2):

That's not specific to state management. There are currently no flutter packages that you can use in the web.

To solve this temporary issue, you need to fork each package you want to use, and change a few things:

- All imports to a flutter file must be changed from `import 'package:flutter/<whatever>` into `import 'package:flutter_web/<whatever>`
- change the `pubspec.yaml`

from:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

into

```
dependencies:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

Comment: I did this already trying to make `flutter_redux` to work and I got into other issues: https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/128

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after long hours on this thing I finally made it work...I think. What I did was forking the `flutter_redux` repo and changing the import references as Rémi also pointed out but that wasn't enough because I still had an error in my IDE complaining about `StoreProvider` with: `The return type 'StoreProvider<AppState>' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by the method 'build'.`.

In `flutter_redux` you also need to edit this file (the only one in lib actually) `flutter_redux/lib/flutter_redux.dart` and alter the import in order to work with `flutter_web`: https://github.com/ciokan/flutter_redux/commit/e8a4f099925c2960cc1bd68aa193f8f38dbd01d5

My compiler is giving me thumbs up now, I still don;t have a full working redux but I suspect the hard part was done.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no state management in flutter_web, my temporary workaround is to pass state in [navigation arguments](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).